# Lecture notes with unclear assumption about statistical learning theory

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, machine-learning

Consider the following introduction to a framework for statistical learning theory, taken from [here](http://www-m5.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M5/Allgemeines/MA4801_2018S/ML_notes_main.pdf):

[image]

[image]

These paragraphs contain a number of unclear points (in decreasing order or importance for me):

1) Is the domain of the random variables $(X_i,Y_i)$ also $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$, like its codomain?

2) What are the "usual topologies" on  $\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y}$? The notes don't make any assumption about what the sets  $\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y}$ might be, so it seems very awkward to suddenly assume they carry some topology.
Furthermore it is stated that *every* function is assumed to be a Borel function, and thus implicitly *every* domain and codomain of every function are assumed to carry a topology. Weird.

3) Why do we have two notation for the probability of an event, $P(A)$ and $\mathbb{P}[A]$? Doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: (4) seems to be implied by the "identically and independently distributed according to some probability measure $P$" statement

Comment: @Henry ah, right, so (4) is solved. I'll remove it from the list. I wanted to use strikethrough but apparently that does not work.

Comment: I'm wondering, are these questions so hard that I received no answer so far?... Unfortunately, I can't offer bounty yet.

Comment: @user719220 Please comment on my answer so that I can shed light if anything is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to frame statistical learning into the usual probability theory setting.

Consider $(\Omega,\mathcal A, Q)$ an arbitrary probability space. Let $(\mathcal X,\mathcal B(\mathcal X))$ and $(\mathcal Y,\mathcal B(\mathcal Y))$ be the input and output spaces equipped with their Borel sigma-algebra. Popular choices are $\mathcal X=\mathbb R^d$ and $\mathcal Y=\mathbb R$.

Let $P$ be a probability measure over $(\mathcal X \times \mathcal Y, \mathcal B(\mathcal X) \otimes \mathcal B(\mathcal Y))$ and $(X,Y):\Omega \to \mathcal X \times \mathcal Y$ be a random element. $(X,Y)$ is distributed according to $P$ if the pushforward measure of $Q$ by $(X,Y)$ is $P$:
$$\forall C\in \mathcal B(\mathcal X) \otimes \mathcal B(\mathcal Y), Q((X,Y)\in C) = P(C)$$

Comment: +1 thanks for the answer! I had already almost given up hope of receiving one, hence I didn't check into my account so often and saw this answer only now. With "random element" you just mean "measurable function", right ? Would you agree with me that the author means that $P(A)$ and $\mathbb{P}[A]$ mean the same thing?